# How to add swipe behavior to the screens?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

We have bottom navigation in our app and we want to add swipe behavior into our screens so that if a user swipe to right/left then s/he should be navigated into next screen.

I know that [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/) has `HorizontalPager` with Tabs. But I wonder if we can achieve that behavior with bottom navigation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see in the [Material Design Guidelines](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior):

> Using swipe gestures on the content area does not navigate between views.

Also:

> Avoid using lateral motion to transition between views.

But, if you really want to do this, you can do the this:

```kotlin
fun BottomNavSwipeScreen() {
    // This scope is necessary to change the tab using animation
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    // I'm using a list of images here
    val images = listOf(R.drawable.img1, ...) 
    // This page state will be used by BottomAppbar and HorizontalPager
    val pageState = rememberPagerState(pageCount = images.size)
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState() 
    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                content = {
                    for (page in images.indices) {
                        BottomNavigationItem(
                            icon = { 
                                Icon(Icons.Filled.Home, "Page $page") 
                            },
                            // here's the trick. the selected tab is based
                            // on HorizontalPager state.
                            selected = page == pageState.currentPage,
                            onClick = {
                                // When a tab is selected, 
                                // the page is updated
                                scope.launch {
                                    pageState.animateScrollToPage(page)
                                }
                            },
                            selectedContentColor = Color.Magenta,
                            unselectedContentColor = Color.LightGray,
                            label = { Text(text = "Page $page") }
                        )
                    }
                }
            )
        },
    ) {
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pageState,
            offscreenLimit = 2
        ) { page ->
            Image(
                painterResource(id = images[page]),
                null,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But we have different screens. Anyway, let me try and will get back to you.

Comment: I'm using a list of images, but you can replace for whatever you want...

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. But back button's behavior was changed. Also, the screens are not recomposed if you come back from another screen

Comment: When I swipe to the last screen, the selected state of bottom navigation for the last screen is changed with some delay (1-2 sec). It happens only with the last screen, the other screens seem to work fine. Do you also have that behavior?

Comment: Yes. It's also happening to me and looks like this a bug to be fixed in the next version.
https://github.com/google/accompanist/issues/395

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: Oh! I just checked... Looks like it's fixed in 0.9.1 ;)

Comment: Haha. But they introduced another bug: whenever you scroll back (to left) then bottom navigation state is not updated anymore

Comment: Oh crap! :( That's true

Comment: I talked to Chris Banes and he fixed that. But it will be only available on next release.
https://github.com/google/accompanist/pull/400

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve this by using the animation library from compose:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation

And using the `slideIntoContainer` animation you can simulate the swipe effect:

```
 composable("route1",
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 250,
                    easing = LinearEasing // interpolator
                )
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 250,
                    easing = LinearEasing
                )
            )
        }) {
        Screen1()
    }
    composable("route2",
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 250,
                    easing = LinearEasing // interpolator
                )
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                towards = AnimatedContentScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 250,
                    easing = LinearEasing
                )
            )
        }) {
        Screen2()
    }
```

Comment: Does it work with touch swipe gesture?

Comment: If your screens are in a horizontalPager, yes

Comment: So you mean these `composable()` functions should all be inside a HorizontalPager? Or each of these `composable()` functions can contain a separate HorizontalPager?

Comment: So, to enable the swipe gesture feature, you have to put your components inside a HorizontalPager, as it enables you to swipe between components.

`fun PagerContent(
    tabs: List<PagerItem>,
    pagerState: PagerState,
) {
    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        count = tabs.size,
    ) { page ->
        tabs[page].screen()
    }
}`

Where `PagerItem` is a `component( )` that you want to display on a screen.